# Loop through selected cells in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I just started learning Vb.net. In VBA, i can loop through selected cells like this and change the case for all cells in the selection

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Selection
    If c.HasFormula = False Then
        c.Value = UCase(c.Value)
    End If
Next
```

How do i achieve this in VB.Net, bearing in mind that I don't already know what range of cells will be selected

Comment: See this:http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_read_entire_worksheet.htm

Answer (score 0):

Ok give this a try. I'm using a `DataGridView` to give the user some cells to select. When the user clicks the "Show Selected" button a `For Each` loop goes through each selected cell.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim gridSelection As New DataGridView
Dim lblSelection As New Label
Dim Selection As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Setup DataGridView
    gridSelection.Columns.Add("columnA", "A")
    gridSelection.Columns.Add("columnB", "B")
    gridSelection.Columns.Add("columnC", "C")
    gridSelection.Columns.Add("columnD", "D")
    gridSelection.Rows.Add(6)
    gridSelection.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    gridSelection.AutoSize = True

    'Setup Button to show Selection
    Dim btnShow As New Button
    btnShow.Text = "Show Selected"
    btnShow.Location = New Point(0, 250)
    btnShow.AutoSize = True
    AddHandler btnShow.Click, AddressOf btnShow_Click

    'Setup label to display Selection
    lblSelection.Text = Nothing
    lblSelection.Location = New Point(0, 300)
    lblSelection.AutoSize = True

    'Add controls to form
    Me.Controls.AddRange({gridSelection, btnShow, lblSelection})
End Sub

Sub btnShow_Click()
    'Reset Selection list.
    Selection = Nothing

    'Loop through each selected cell.
    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In gridSelection.SelectedCells
        Dim column As String = cell.OwningColumn.HeaderText
        Dim row As String = cell.RowIndex.ToString()

        'Add cell to Selection list.
        Selection = IIf(Selection = Nothing, Selection, Selection + ", ") + column + row
    Next

    'Show Selection list.
    lblSelection.Text = Selection
End Sub
End Class
```

Hope this paints a better picture for you.

Comment: I know how to run a basic loop in Vb.net but what i really needed is how the exact VBA code i posted would look like in Vb.net. to change all currently selected cell's case to UPPER

Comment: Right `c = c.ToUpper` will do this for you in VB.net. Sorry if I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: Thanks @supersnake Let me try give more details. Assuming a user selects cells, A1,C2 and D3, one can use a code like <code>For each cell in selection</code> to perform operations on just those selected cells. if i were to do this vb.net, how would i do that? What's the equivalent of "Selection" in vb.net. I hope this helps to make my question clearer